# Satellizer and Yahoo OAuth1.0

Tags: angularjs, yahoo-api, satellizer

Has anyone successfully used Satellizer (https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) to connect to the Yahoo API's using Oauth1.0 ? I can get the Oauth2.0 working, but I have to use 1.0 to access the Fantasy Sports API. In my angular module I declare the oauth1.0 settings as such..

```
$authProvider.oauth1({
        name: 'yahoo',
        url: '/auth/yahoo',
        authorizationEndpoint: 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token',
        redirectUri: '/auth/yahoo/callback',
        type: '1.0',
        popupOptions: { width: 559, height: 519 },
        type: "1.0",
        clientId: 'my-client-id',
    });
```

Because I need to obtain a request_token first, I'm not sure how to set it up.

Comment: You need to show your server code also